# VBA Document.Protect not setting wdProtectionType (Office 2007)

Tags: vba, automation, ms-office, ms-word

I would like to automate the process of protecting a word document for comments only using Office 2007 VBA's Document.Protect. This works fine if the document has no protection yet, but fails once the protection has ever been set before.

The following is a minimal working example that shows the bug I am facing (see below). I have reproduced on another PC running Office 2007 SP3. The problem occurs even with a blank document.

To reproduce, use the following macro after saving a new blank document:

```
Sub ProtectionBugOffice2007()

    ' Apply a first type of locking to simulate an existing lock
    RecentFiles(1).Open
    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then ActiveDocument.Unprotect
    ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields
    ActiveDocument.Close (wdSaveChanges)

    ' Now do the real test: Lock with our intended protection type
    RecentFiles(1).Open
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect
    ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyComments
    ActiveDocument.Close (wdSaveChanges)

    ' Validate!
    RecentFiles(1).Open
    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyComments Then
        MsgBox "Success!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Failure! Should be " & wdAllowOnlyComments & " but is " & ActiveDocument.ProtectionType
    End If
    ActiveDocument.Close

End Sub
```

**Things investigated before:**

- Office 2007 is up to date with SP 3 and latest windows update
- If performed manually protection type can be changed correctly, but recorded as macro fails.
- Other types of saving the document (Document.Save or Document.SaveAs(2))
- Disabling ReadingLayout `ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False` (see Alredo's answer): No change in Office 2007

**Edits:**

- 2015-10-23: Initial problem
- 2015-10-25: Minimal working example added.
- 2015-10-25: Discovered that only after manually or programmatically setting the protection type it can no longer be changed.
- 2015-10-26: Offered bounty

Comment: I did a few readings to check the protect function, but you seems to do it well... And you code works fine for me... I would only suggest that you used an object for better control on references as `ActiveDocument` can easily change during runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works for you? In which Office Version?

Comment: 2010 64bits, works like a charm... And when I retried on a protected document and got an error message saying it wasn't possible, so I can't get an understanding of where your issue can be...

Comment: I am closing in on it: It seems that if I manually set to `wdAllowOnlyFormFields`, then the protect call cannot change this value anymore. If you get an error, try to unprotect first (manually or by using `ActiveDocument.unprotect`)

Comment: Ok, I know/guessed about the `unprotect` method, but did you try to use it to before settings your new value for `protectiontype`? You don't seem to have a lot of points on VBA tag, are familiar with it?

Comment: Sure, I unprotect in case the document is protected. I am doing most of the coding not inside VBA but using COM automation in AHK. The problem is the same though. I guess it is a bug in Office 2007.

Comment: Are you running the latest service pack / updates for your Office 2007? Your code is also working fine in on 2010 32bit so as you say it's possibly an issue specific to 2007 which may have been fixed in an update.

Comment: Up to date with SP 3. It seems the code is working if the user has not manually set another protection type before. While it is possible to unprotect, the new protectiontype is not applied.

Comment: Is this happening with just the one document (or documents created from a particular template)? If you test on a new document can you repro the behavior? If it looks like it may be document-/template-specific the problem may be caused by a damaged (corrupt) file.

Comment: I reproduced on another machine and with just a blank document/template. See code to test above.

Comment: I know for certain that you can set the protection type in the underlying XML package. How far are you willing to go for a solution? :-) Note: This only works for OpenXML-format files.

Comment: Just to add to line of thought; this issue does appear to specific to 2007 and the DOCX format. If you run this code in 2007 but use a DOC format file then it does correctly change protection type. I can only conclude from this that there is a bug within 2007s VBA `Protect`  / `Unprotect` functions which results in these not being applied correctly in these circumstances to the new files. You could possibly mess with the XML as suggested above otherwise it may be easier to either downgrade to the DOC format or upgrade to 2010...

Comment: @andshrew I am unsure about which document format would be a good intermediate target. I definitely need to end up again in docx (formatting templates, document properties, etc. are used).

Comment: @DanL Can you describe how to go about this? Do you think along using XPath or similar to set an XML tag?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek In the XML package, in the settings.xml file, you can change the protection in the attributes of the documentProtection node. I can post a .NET example of this as an answer if you want.

Comment: I have only availability to commands from VBA using AHK. Can you post an example?

Comment: VBA is a little more tedious. This link should help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819387(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research online and the code failing on me several times. I found a post that solved my problem which was caused because word opens secured documents in reading view.

This is a link to the original post [Link to post](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/10/03/how-to-disable-reading-view-in-word-2013-preview.aspx)

```
Sub ProtectionBugOffice2007()

    Dim oDoc As Document

    ' Apply a first type of locking to simulate an existing lock
    Set oDoc = OpenRecentNotReadOnly

    If oDoc.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then oDoc.Unprotect
    oDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields
    oDoc.Close (wdSaveChanges)

    ' Now do the real test: Lock with our intended protection type
    Set oDoc = OpenRecentNotReadOnly
    oDoc.Unprotect
    oDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyComments
    oDoc.Close (wdSaveChanges)

    ' Validate!
    Set oDoc = OpenRecentNotReadOnly
    If oDoc.ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyComments Then
        MsgBox "Success!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Failure! Should be " & wdAllowOnlyComments & " but is " & oDoc.ProtectionType
    End If
    oDoc.Close

End Sub

' Function to open the document not in read only.
Function OpenRecentNotReadOnly() As Document

    Dim ret As Document

    Set ret = RecentFiles(1).Open
    ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False

    'Return the value
    Set OpenRecentNotReadOnly = ret
End Function
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I can see how that might be a problem, but I have disabled the option to open in Reading Layout and improved the sample code. Still the problem is there for me (office 2007). ` if (oDoc.ActiveWindow and oDoc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout) oDoc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not help under Office 2007.